# how can I compile less files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less

I am new to less. It sounds appealing!

Goal:

- compile one less file to more css files ( for theme based css):

Setup:

main.less imports variables.less (variables contains different color schema's)

```
Folder structure
\main.less
\variables.less
\theme\christmass\variables.less
\theme\newyear\variables.less
```

I want to call lesscss for each variables.less (which contains the different colors)

```
lesscss main.less main.css
lesscss main.less main{theme}.css path={theme_christmaspad}/variables.less
lesscss main.less main{theme}.css path={theme_newyearpad}/variables.less
```

Problems:

I cant seem to set the pre-build event of visual studio to compile the css! How can I make this work?

This is the error message:

```
Error   1   The command "lessc" exited with code 9009
```

Comment: You might have better luck using a plugin like Web Essentials: http://vswebessentials.com/features/less

Comment: I use this now. But there is no to give compile options per file. Also   there is not a way to import a file with a dynamic path. I used another solution to my problem. I will post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a different approuch, I did make use of Web Essentials

for every theme i created a file themex.less where I

1. import main variables (this is not in main file because of error with webessentials)
2. import main file
3. import theme variables which ovverrides the main variables

thats it, pretty simple and straightforward.